# Count number of entries user has in another table with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, count

I'm trying to create a view in SQL which will check how many holidays a member of staff has taken in a year from a holiday table ( example, staffid 1 is entered into the holiday table 4 times so it would display staffid: 1 holidaycount: 4 )

I tried to write it as this:

```
select 
       holiday.staffid,
       staff.staffid,
       COUNT(*)
from
       staff
inner join holiday on staff.staffid = holiday.staffid

group by staff.staffid;
```

This gives me the error: ORA-00918: column  ambiguously defined

edit: Changed code as it was incorrect

Comment: there's no `holiday` table within the query ... The error should be this or query should be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something along these lines:

```
select s.staffid, count(h.staffid) no_holidays
from staff s
left join holiday h 
    on  h.staffid = a.staffid
    and h.holiday_date >= current_date - interval '1' year
group by s.staffid;
```

The `left join` brings corresponding records in `holiday`, while allowing staff that did not take any holiday. I added a filter on the `holiday_date`, that is described in the question. You can then aggregate and `count`.

You could also express this with a lateral join or a subquery, which make it easier to display more columns from `staff`:

```
select 
    s.*, 
    (
        select count(*) 
        from holiday h 
        where h.staffid = a.staffid and h.holiday_date >= current_date - interval '1' year

    ) no_holidays
from staff s
```

Comment: Perfect! second solution was just what I needed, I wasn't sure how I could access all of the staff data and the holiday information so I dropped that goal but you've sorted it! I seem to be getting some errors on SQL Developer but it is displaying the correct information

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work, you are missing `holiday` table in `join` condition. Also if both the `staffid's` are same then use one of them only.

```
select 
   staff.staffid,
   COUNT(*)
from staff

inner join holiday 
on staff.staffid = holiday.staffid

group by 
    staff.staffid;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to join both tables with `staffid` and count the `holiday_id`(the primary key for your holiday table) becasue `count(*)` may not be exactly useful for you

```
select 
       staff.staffid,
       COUNT(holiday_id)
from holiday
inner join staff on staff.staffid = holiday.staffid
group by staff.staffid;
```